# Having trouble with the responsive layout of my website

Tags: html, css, height, width, responsive

I want to make a slideshow with the captions on the side. I want the slideshow to take **70%** width of the screen, and the captions to take **30%** width of the screen. I want the two to resize to any screen size. Also, the height of both elements have to be **100%** in height.

This is my CSS and HTML:

```css
/*Slidetrack*/
#slidetrack{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

#slider{
  width:70%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

#slide1 {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

#caption-holder{
  color: #000;
  background: #fff;
  border: #e6e6e6 15px solid;
  width: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.dot{


}

.caption {

}

.caption h1, p{

}

.fade {

}
```

```html
<main id="slidetrack">

      <div id="slider">
      <div id="slide1"><img src="img/tennis.jpg"></div>
      <div id="slide2"></div>
      <div id="slide3"></div>
      </div>

      <div id="caption-holder">
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>
        <span class="dot"></span>

        <div class="caption">
          <h1>Lorep Ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
          <h1>Lorep Ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>

        <div class="caption">
          <h1>Lorep Ipsum</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </main>
```

[This is a screenshot of what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw44H.jpg)

the slidetrack on this website is exactly what I want to do, but mine is "fullscreen": http://design-milk.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your .caption-holder element has a 15px border all around, which adds 30px of space that is unaccounted for by the width: 30% value. You can either add the property: box-sizing: border-box, that will force the width to include padding border sizes in its calculations, or adjust width to width: calc(30% - 30px) to manually account for the border width yourself. Either option will bump up the caption-holder to be side by side for you.

Comment: You're welcome! Could you tag my post as accepted answer, please? :)